# How to connect capacitive touch sensor to Arduino?

Tags: sensors, arduino-micro

The capacitive touch sensor has 3 pinouts: Vin, GND, and OUT and emits an active high signal when the pad is touched. I should be routing the OUT pin to any one of the digital input pins on my Arduino Micro, correct?

Also, I need to power 2 of these capacitive touch sensors along with an IMU. How do you power multiple sensors on the Arduino Micro? There is only one GND pin and one 5 V pin. I would prefer if it could be done without a breadboard as this entire setup will be placed in a stylus.

Answer (score 1):

> The capacitative touch sensor has 3 pinouts: Vin, GND, and OUT and emits an active high signal when the pad is touched. I should be routing the OUT pin to any one of the digital input pins on my arduino micro, correct?

Probably, yes. Without more details about what the sensor is we can't really comment.

> Also, I need to power 2 of these capacitative touch sensors along with an IMU. How do you power multiple sensors on the arduino micro? There is only one GND pin and one 5 V pin. I would prefer if it could be done without a breadboard as this entire setup will be placed in a stylus.

You can plug as many (within reason) items into the +5V and GND pins as you like. You can twist wires together, use screw terminal blocks, breadboard, solder, whatever you like, to connect the wires together to a single wire that goes to the pin.